# Select the date of a UserIDs first/most recent purchase

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working with Google Analytics data in BigQuery, looking to aggregate the date of last visit and first visit up to UserID level, however my code is currently returning the max visit date for that user, so long as they have purchased within the selected date range, because I am using `MAX()`.

If I remove `MAX()` I have to `GROUP` by `DATE`, which I don't want as this then returns multiple rows per UserID.

Here is my code which returns a series of dates per user - `last_visit_date` is currently working, as it's the only date that can simply look at the last date of user activity. Any advice on how I can get `last_ord_date` to select the date on which the order actually occurred?

```
SELECT
  customDimension.value AS UserID,
  # Last order date
  IF(COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId) > 0,
    (MAX(DATE)),
    "unknown") AS last_ord_date,

  # first visit date
  IF(SUM(totals.newvisits) IS NOT NULL,
    (MAX(DATE)),
    "unknown") AS first_visit_date,

  # last visit date
  MAX(DATE) AS last_visit_date,

  # first order date
  IF(COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId) > 0,
    (MIN(DATE)),
    "unknown") AS first_ord_date

FROM
  `XXX.XXX.ga_sessions_20*` AS t
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST (hits) AS hits
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST(t.customdimensions) AS customDimension
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST(hits.product) AS hits_product
WHERE
  parse_DATE('%y%m%d',
    _table_suffix) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 day)
  AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 day)
  AND customDimension.index = 2
  AND customDimension.value NOT LIKE "true"
  AND customDimension.value NOT LIKE "false"
  AND customDimension.value NOT LIKE "undefined"
  AND customDimension.value IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  UserID
```

Comment: Arrays can be such a bad way to store things.  Sample data and desired results would help others make sense of what you want to do.

Comment: Usually it is not good thing to expose real project id in public forums - you probably can put placeholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most efficient and clear way to do this (and also most portable) is to have a simple table/view that has two columns: userid, last_purchase and another that has other two cols userid, first_visit.

then you inner join it with the original raw table on userid and hit timestamp to get, say, the session IDs you're interested in. 3 steps but simple, readable and easy to maintain

It's very easy to hit too much complexity for a query that relies on first or last purchase/action (just look at the unnest operations you have there) that is becomes unusable and you'll spend way too much time trying to figure out the meaning of the output.

Also keep in mind that using the wildcard in the query has a limit of 1000 tables, so your last and first visits are in a rolling window of 1000 days.

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense, my second approach was to create sub tables with the data in, but you raise a very good point that effort may be wasted in the search for a 'perfect' single query!

Comment: awesome! let me know if it worked! I used to do many of these for Churn analysis and it's a nightmare. When you want to add a new feature you need to re write everything. Making the query modular made my life much simpler back then =)