# Group by: calculated field to return respective date in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, calculated-field

I need to do an user level analysis. As the data has a lot of different rows per user (related to different events), I need to group by user and create some calculated fields that represent the different rows. One of the fields is a calculation of the number of days since the last purchase of the user (today - last purchase date). I already tried a lot of different codes and also did a lot of research, but could not find the solution.

The codes that for me makes more sense but did not work are below:

## Using case when statement

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LAST(tr_orderid <> "") THEN 
DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),event_date) ELSE NULL END AS recency_lastbooking
FROM df
GROUP BY domain_userid
```

## Using IF statement

```
SELECT IF(LAST(tr_total > 0), DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),event_date), NULL) 
AS recency_lastbooking
FROM df
GROUP BY domain_userid
```

The error that I get is: **Expression 'event_date' is not present in the GROUP BY list**

I think if I use LAST(event_date) the query will return the last date in all the lines of the specific user, instead of return the last day the user had a purchase event.

P.S: I can use tr_total (total transaction) > 0 or tr_orderid (transaction order id) <> ""

Thank you!

Comment: I have done this previously by first creating a table with the last order data by user id, then joining to bring in this field. I found it to be a cleaner approach. Here's my question, you may find it useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878221/select-the-date-of-a-userids-first-most-recent-purchase

Comment: Thank you Ben! That is the exact same thing my colleague told me now. I will try it!

Comment: it is not clear what your case is. you should provide simplified example of your input and expected output. and clarify logic of what you are trying to achieve. just showing wrong and not working code alone - does not help

Comment: I am sorry, Mikhail. I will keep it in mind for the next one. But my problem was exactly the same as my colleague above. His question helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want a window function:

```
SELECT DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE,
                 MAX(tr_orderid) OVER (PARTITION BY domain_userid),
                 day
                ) AS recency_lastbooking
FROM df;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you! But my problem was the same as the colleague above. His question helped me.

Comment: @BrunaAranha . . . There is no reason at all to create another table.